# How Does my Node.js Server know it's Production and not Local?

Tags: node.js

After Finally Deploying the most basic of Node.js scripts to an EC2 server to try it out, my server displays my app on :3000 like its on development instead of production.  I can't find anything about it which makes me think it is so simple no one would ever not know how to do it except me, what do I need to do here to get my EC2 server knowing it is the production server?

```
var port;
app.configure('development', function(){
port = 3000;
app.use(express.errorHandler({ dumpExceptions: true, showStack: true }));
});

app.configure('production', function(){
port = 80;
app.use(express.errorHandler());

});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Command Line

```
$ NODE_ENV=production node app.js
```

In app

```
process.env.NODE_ENV = 'production'
```

Comment: Just to be add, Express uses this environment variable (NODE_ENV) to determine which app.configure option to use.